# Как поставить лимит на размер файла, как узнать размер файла?

Tags: java, файлы

Я создала массив и записала в файл. Мне нужно определить какой-нибудь лимит для размера файла. Если размер файла превышает лимит, нужно сбросить собственное исключение

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(5);
    list.add(6);
    list.add(7);

    try {


FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/Users/macbookair/Desktop/1.txt");
        fw.write(String.valueOf(list));
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Так что не получается?

Comment: не представляю как это делается

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092861/limit-file-size-while-writing-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задаете переменную с лимитом размера в битах.

```
... //запись в файл, потом вызов checkFileLength()

public static void checkFileLength(String fileName) { //проверка размера файла

 long limit = ...;

 File f = new File(fileName);
 long len = f.length();

 if(limit < len)
  throw new Exeption("Лимит файла превышен");
}
```

Comment: Этот метод проверяет размер файла после записи, то есть выбросит исключение, если лимит на размер файла - 10 килобайт, но я в него уже записал 10 гигабайт.

Comment: Т.е., вы хотите сказать, что он дает записать больше, чем лимит? Ну, в вопросе написано так: "Если размер файла превышает лимит, нужно сбросить собственное исключение", т.е. сначала запись, потом проверка. Или нет?

Comment: Может я неправильно понял автора вопроса, но мне кажется, что для него важен размер файла после записи в него `list`, а не до. С другой стороны, ваш ответ он принял. так что я могу и ошибаться.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev  "мне кажется, что для него важен размер файла после записи в него `list`" - ну да, так у меня он как раз и проверяет размер файла после записи. Может, он принял мой ответ, потому что он проще для новичка. Допустим мне не понятно, как в результате этой строки получается размер файла `(list.size() * Integer.BYTES)`?

Comment: В результате этой строки получается размер списка - количество его элементов умноженное на размер одного элемента в байтах. Что приблизительно равно размеру файла.

Comment: Да, я приняла Ваш ответ, так как проще было для понимания. И я девушка:)

Answer (score 1):

```
class LimitExceededException extends Exception {
    ...
}

public class Solution {
    private static final long SIZE_LIMIT = 42;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
        if ((list.size() * Integer.BYTES) > SIZE_LIMIT) {
            throw new LimitExceededException("Some message")
        }
    }
}
```